# `Dynamic`caly change values of an association

Tags: dynamic, associations

Here are two attempts to make a slider that changes an value of an association.

```
In[1]:= assoc=<|a->0.5|>
Out[1]= <|a->0.5|>

In[2]:= Slider[Dynamic[assoc[a]]]
Out[2]= \!\(
SliderBox[Dynamic[$CellContext`assoc[$CellContext`a]]]\)

In[3]:= slider[assoc_]:=Slider[Dynamic[assoc[a]]]

In[4]:= slider[assoc]
Out[4]= \!\(
SliderBox[Dynamic[<|$CellContext`a -> 0.5|>[$CellContext`a]]]\)
```

The first slider (Out[2]) works, but the second slider (Out[4]) does not.
From the text form of the output it seems that I need to use a different definition of `slider` to make the function work. How can I do this, and what is really going on behind the scenes? That is, why are the two sliders different?

Edit: so this fixes the immediate issue.

```
SetAttributes[slider, HoldAll]
```

I think now I kind of see why this works, but any more precise, in-depth answers to the question will help a lot. Should I use `HoldAll/HoldFirst` family of attributes to pass parameters 'by reference' instead of 'by value'?

Comment: An alternative to `HoldAll` and its siblings is show [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html#653078519) in Advanced Manipulate Tutorial.

Comment: This is a common pitfall, take a look at [18737](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18737/5478)